# adb pull -p option shows over 100% progress

Tags: android, progress, dump, pull, computer-forensics

I used adb pull for getting image from my device.
and it shows like below picture.
(But there was no problem at all. just strange percentage only.)

[adb pull -p DeviceImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZoHT.png)
Anyone has an idea why this is happened??